# React state object updating and sending it ot database

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

I'm writing some app where creating projects with some data inside. 1 of the fields is `members`.It is array of project members(object inside array). I have a project update functionality, but there is a problem while I'm updating member data in project. On my server side I always recieve old data.

Method witch updates state of members array. It finds needed object (member which should be updated) and updates its data

```
updateMember(data){

        let objectIndex = this.state.members.filter((member,index) => {
            if(data.id === member.id) return index;
            return -1;
        })

        if(objectIndex !== -1){

            let stateCopy = Object.assign({},this.state);
            stateCopy.members[objectIndex] = data;

            this.setState({
                members: stateCopy.members
            })           

        }

    }
```

Then I'm doing data submit by click on button and sending state data to some action which makes query to `REST API`.
Before sending data to the server I did `console.log()` to be sure about data I send. I got [image]
But on the server inside `request.body` I recieve only old objects from members array. I have no idea why it happens. Maybe I'm doing something wrong... Looking for your help and advices.

Comment: where do you have a API call, is it in the updateMember function itself or a different one

Comment: `setState` is async; you cannot call `setState` then immediately read from state without waiting at least a single event loop tick.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be that [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is asyncronous and calling it does not result in immediate update of `this.state` value.

Check if you are submiting data immediately after call to `setState` - and if so - make sure to do this in the callback function that can be passed to `setState` as next argument.

Comment: I'm setting state(updating some member inside members array). After that I'm clincking on button to submit the form (local function where it calls paren'ts method whre I pass object filled `this.state` fields) Parent's method recieves this data and doing action dispatch(this action makes request to the server). this action should recieve some payload to be send on the server, so I'm passing recieved from child argument data to this action

Comment: If I'm doing `console.log(this.state.members)` inside submit function(before calling parent's function) I see the same object in console. `[object Object]` on the picture contains object with changed data... so I don't understand why I'm getting wrong data on server

Comment: When you doing console log - it does not show you the content of the object at the moment of calling. You will see the content of the object at the moment you will expand it to see its content. Try following my advice and put submit call inside the callback argument of the setState function.

Comment: Should it be like `this.setState({
                members: stateCopy.members
            },this.onModalSubmit)` ? inside `this.onModalSubmit` I have `e.preventDefault` so it gives me error about that. And nothing changed with data

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `updateMember` function. 
Change it to:

```
updateMember(data){

        let objectIndex = this.state.members.filter((member,index) => {
            if(data.id === member.id) return index;
            return -1;
        })

        if(objectIndex !== -1){       

            let stateCopy = Object.assign({},this.state);

            stateCopy.members.splice(objectIndex,1, data);

            this.setState({
                members: stateCopy.members
            })

        }

    }
```

And everything works nicely right now